# Error ao tirar foto com a câmera android - GlideException - OnLoadFailed

Tags: android, android-layout, mobile, android-activity

Estou tentando implementar a função de tirar a foto com a câmera no meu app, porém sem estou caindo no tratamento de falha no Glide onLoadFailed. Já testei outras lógicas e não consigo entender o porque de sempre cair no onLoadFailed.

```
private ImageView imageView;
private Button button_enviar;
private Uri uri_imagem = null;
public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 0;
public static final int PICK_IMAGE_CAMERA = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_storage_upload);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagem_storage_upload);
    button_enviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_enviar_storage_upload);

    button_enviar.setOnClickListener(this);

    permissao();
}

// --------------------------------------------------- TRATAMENTO DE CLICKS ---------------------------------------------------

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_enviar_storage_upload:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enviar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------- CRIAR MENU ---------------------------------------------------

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_storage_upload, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item_galeria:
            obterImagem_Galeria();
            return true;
        case R.id.item_camera:
            obterImagem_Camera();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// --------------------------------------------------- OBTER IMAGEM ---------------------------------------------------

private void obterImagem_Galeria() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Ecolha uma Imagem"), PICK_IMAGE);

}

// --------------------------------------------------- OBTER IMAGEM CAMERA -----------------------------------------------------------------------

private void obterImagem_Camera() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File diretorio = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    String nomeImagem = diretorio.getPath()+"/"+"CursoImagem"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";

    File file = new File(nomeImagem);

    String autorizacao = "com.example.gymplus";

    uri_imagem = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getBaseContext(), autorizacao, file);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri_imagem);

    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_CAMERA);

}

// --------------------------------------------------- RESPOSTAS DE COMUNICAÇÃO  -----------------------------------------------------------------------

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode){
        case PICK_IMAGE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                if (data != null) {
                    uri_imagem = data.getData();
                    Glide.with(getBaseContext()).asBitmap().load(uri_imagem).listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Falha ao selecionar Imagem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }).into(imageView);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Falha ao selecionar Imagem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            break;

        case PICK_IMAGE_CAMERA:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                if(uri_imagem != null){
                    Glide.with(getBaseContext()).asBitmap().load(uri_imagem).listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Falha ao tirar Imagem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }).into(imageView);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Falha ao tirar Imagem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    }
}




// ------------------------------------------------------------ PERMISSÕES USUÁRIO ----------------------------------------------------------------

private void permissao() {

    String permissoes[] = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

    Permissao.permissao(this, 0, permissoes);

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    for (int result : grantResults) {
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Aceite as permissões para o aplicativo acessar sua câmera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Arquivo provider.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
          <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
        </paths>
```

Manifests

```
    <provider
        android:authorities="com.example.gymplus"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider"/>
    </provider>
```

Comment: Olá, Lucca! Se é mostrada alguma mensagem de erro, seria interessante [editar sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/375773/edit) e incluí-la. Print `GlideException`

Comment: Boa Noite Ivan! No caso o "erro" que ocorre é na exibição da imagem. O aplicativo obtém sucesso nas etapas de abrir a câmera e tirar a foto, porém a foto tirada não está sendo exibida no ImageView do XML. Realizei alguns teste e conclui que após tirar a fota a condição que avalia se a imagem está realmente retornando uma imagem (uri_image != null) está retornando null e caindo no else exibindo o Toast. Consegui "arrumar", porém utilizando bitmap... mas essa não seria minha primeira opção...

Answer (score 0):

O código do bitmap é:

```
        case PICK_IMAGE_CAMERA:
            status = true;
            if(resultCode != StorageUploadActivity.RESULT_CANCELED){
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
```

Isso resolve o problema, porém não da forma como eu quero... Meu objetivo é tirar uma foto e realizar o upload da mesma com uma resolução considerável..